# How to use range and accumulator functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python and my assignment is giving me a bit of a headache.

My assignment is to :

Write a program that prints a string of the alphabet in order from a-z. Given the strings 'acegikmoqsuwy' and 'bdfhjlnprtvxz' create a third string using the range function in a for loop. Use an accumulator to create the third string.

I really don't understand how to use the accumulator and range function... Ive reviewed over the notes provided by my instructor but they aren't very clear.

So far I have-

```
#Alphabet code
s1 = 'acegikmoqsuwy'
s2 = 'bdfhjlnprtvxz'
s3 = list.sort([s3])
print(s3)
```

Comment: @RoryDaulton no, I understand, it is the typical parlance of imperative programming. They still teach this :) I was trying to say that the question wasn't properly specified, but at first glance, I didn't realize that these strings were simply the alphabet interwoven. Now what the assignment was getting at is obvious enough.

Answer (score 2):

An "accumulator" is a variable that holds the temporary results of a calculation that is being done using a loop. For example, to sum a list of integers, you can set the accumulator variable to zero, then use a loop to add each integer in the list to the accumulator. When the loop is finished, the accumulator's value is the sum of the list.

In your problem, `s1` holds the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th, ... letters of the alphabet, while `s2` holds the 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th, ... letters. You could build up the entire alphabet by taking the first letter in `s1` followed by the first letter in `s2`, then adding the second letter in `s1` followed by the second letter in `s2`, then ... So we can use an accumulator to add each of those letters, one at a time.

The `range(n)` function gives the integers below the value of `n`, starting with `0`. We can use those integers as indices into the `s1` and `s2` strings to get one character at a time. Much more can be said about `range()`--you should read a tutorial to learn more, since this is not a site for tutorials.

Here is some code that does what you want. Note that this depends on the two input strings having the same length--an error occurs otherwise. I changed the variable names to make them more self-documenting. You should note that this code is not "Pythonic" in its use of an index. There are better ways to do this, but they do not use `range()`.

```
string1 = 'acegikmoqsuwy'
string2 = 'bdfhjlnprtvxz'
accum = ''
for index in range(len(string1)):
    accum += string1[index] + string2[index]
print(accum)
```

The printed result is the alphabet:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```